# C# CodeDom Console.WriteLine + MethodReference

Tags: c#, methods, codedom, console.writeline

I am attempting to create a `Console.WriteLine` statement (shown below) using CodeDom. This is giving me mainly because of the `Environment.NewLine` call - I can't figure out the *proper* way of embedding a method within the Console.WriteLine call. I will show you the code I am trying to produce along with the code that I am using. Perhaps someone will be able to catch, and correct my error.

**The code I would *like* to produce:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Error reading from source: " + Environment.NewLine + "Error code: " + ex.Message);
```

**The code that I am using:**

```
const char quote = '\u0022'; // Represents a " mark
CodeMethodInvokeExpression invoke = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("Console"), "WriteLine",
new CodeExpression[] {
new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(quote + "Error reading from source: " + quote + " + "),
new CodeFieldReferenceExpression("Environment"), "NewLine"),
new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("+ " + quote + "Error code: " + quote + " + " + "ex" + ".Message")})));
```

**The code that is being generated:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Error reading source: " + , Environment.NewLine, + "Error code: " + ex.Message);
```

**Because I am using `MethodInvoke`, CodeDom is separating each line by a ", " as if they were each new parameters within the same method... How can I go about this the *proper* way?**

Comment: well you can use the programmer's way of fixing problems - ignore them. You can try `"Error reading source: {0} Error code: {1}"`...

Comment: which is also cleaner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the CodeDOM the same way you write the code normally. That is, when you want to call a method with one argument, you have to give it one argument.

Also, if you want to have a constant in the generated code, the proper way is to use `CodePrimitiveExpression`. You are trying to creating a variable with the name `"Error reading from source: "`.

Because constructing the whole expression by hand would be tedious and unreadable, you could create a helper method for joining multiple expressions using the same operator:

```
static CodeExpression Join(
    CodeBinaryOperatorType op, params CodeExpression[] expressions)
{
    return expressions.Aggregate((l, r) => new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(l, op, r));
}
```

Using that, you can now write:

```
new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Console)), "WriteLine",
    Join(CodeBinaryOperatorType.Add,
            new CodePrimitiveExpression("Error reading from source: "),
            new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
                new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Environment)),
                "NewLine"),
            new CodePrimitiveExpression("Error code: "),
            new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
                new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("ex"), "Message")));
```

Which produces the following code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(((("Error reading from source: " + System.Environment.NewLine)
                + "Error code: ")
                + ex.Message))
```

Of course, you can always use snippets:

```
new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Console)), "WriteLine",
    new CodeSnippetExpression(
        "\"Error reading from source: \" + Environment.NewLine + \"Error code: \" + ex.Message"));
```

Also, using the formatting overload of `Console.WriteLine()` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Console.WriteLine(String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) overload and do the equivalent to

```
Console.WriteLine("Error reading from source: {0} Error code: {1}", 
    Environment.NewLine, 
    ex.Message);
```

in CodeDom.

Comment: alright - I'll be able to test this out shortly. I'll report back once I've got it working. Thank you.